# Reference request: Network/graph topology inference

Tags: references, graph-theory, networks, topologies

I am a mathematician looking for a survey/book on methods for inference of graph/network topology (structure). Specifically, the kind of problem I am looking to study is as follows:

> Given a graph $G$ consider an unknown function $f$ such that $f(G)=y$ (for a real number $y$). Assume we have a collection of graphs ($G_1, G_2, \dots, G_n$) for which the values $f(G_k)=y_k$ are known. Given a proposed value $y_*$:
>
> - **How can one reconstruct a graph $\hat{G}_*$ such that $f(\hat{G}_*)\approx y_*$?**
> - **How about confidence intervals or high-density regions in some space of graphs?**

What I am not interested in is:

- A book such as Durrett's *Random Graph Dynamics* which presents specific probabilistic models of graph generation but no inference.
- Kolaczyk's *Statistical Analysis of Network Data* which focuses on inferring part of a network's topological descriptors but not the whole network.

Comment: A similar reference request exists at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27480/254158)

Comment: @sboysel The request at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27480/what-are-good-books-to-learn-graph-theory) is looking for books on graph theory not for _statistical inference_ on graphs.

Comment: Since $f$ is unknown, I think the first step would be to estimate $f$ before trying to solve the inverse problem $G = f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: Sounds like a great first step. Do you have any references? I'm still looking (two years into this)